# setting up physics body from code when using required init(nscoder)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, initialization, physics

I'm attempting to take advantage of the init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) function so that I can subclass sprites in my sks file.

I can set the physics body in the sks file, but it doesn't work too well with my rectangular sprites I'm using that also have rounded corners. Because of the rounded corners, prior to using the init function, I was setting up the physicsbody in code, and setting the width slightly smaller than the squares width (that way when my hero slides off the square, there isn't a gap where the rounded corner is..

I know I can use the alpha mask physics body to get the same affect, except that with this, There seems to be a 1 px'ish gap when my hero is on the blocks, and it doesn't look good.

Wondering the reason why I can't set the physics body this, and also how I can do it or get around it?

Thanks for any help!!!

**Update:**

```
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    if let p = userData?.value(forKey: "col") as? String {
        setup(p)
        print("working")
    }
}
func setup(_ col: String) {
    setupPhysics()
    //allSprites.append(self)
```

In the setupPhysics I have:

```
override func setupPhysics() {
    physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: frame.width - 4, height: frame.height - 1))
...more code...
}
```

This is my code for the sprite, and I have it correctly setup in the sks file...

I commented out the append to allSprites, so that I can demonstrate that it doesn't work. With the append uncommented, the sprites get added to allSprites, and then in my didMove function in the Scene file, it loops through allSprites and runs the setupPhysics():

```
  func setup(_ col: String) {
    //setupPhysics()
    allSprites.append(self)

// scene file
    func setupAllSpritesPhysics() {
    for sprite in allSprites { sprite.setupPhysics() }
}
```

@Knight0fDragon :

You mention that this is an ugly fix. I disagree given the fact that it won't work the 'correct' way. And currently I don't have enough sprites to cause any kind of lag in the scene loading. I can look into that in the future if that is the case.

I'll admit I haven't tried the method you mentioned because I don't want to create a child node for each sprite I create in order to get around this even if it works. I appreciate the advice so far though.

Comment: it would help if you showed some more info. if the hero physics is setup in code show that code or show an image showing what is happening when the sprites interact. The more info you can provide the easier it is to figure out your issues.

Comment: Thanks for the comments,  i don't have my computer in front of me at the moment but I will update the question when I get a chance. I can say, that the init function functions correctly and works, I only have 1 init function. THe function that sets up the physics is called after super.init is called. I did get it too work using a wait skaction with a completion closure... so I assume the super.init needs more time to finish, but that seems kind of hacky...

Comment: did you even check to see if that print line is happening

Comment: also are you hitting the correct setup method

Comment: yes of course on first question and yes it is correct setup function

Comment: also, it is not ugly?  What happens when you have a million sprites on the screen?, You will be creating all your spites, then going through a loop of a million to setup bodies,  causing an awkward delay and a longer load time

Comment: I get the point, I prefer to not do it this way, reason why I'm on here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make this work with the SKS file, I would add a child SKNode with the dimensions of the body you want, and then in the Custom class code, do

```
required init(coder aDecoder:NSCoder){
    super.init(coder:aDecoder)
    if let child = childNode(withName:"child"), let physicsBody = child.physicsBody{
       self.physicsBody = physicsBody
       child.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

What we are doing here is transfering the physics body from the child to the parent, and then killing the child off.  This allows our code to be a little more dynamic, and keeps design seperate from functionality.

Well, nice little bug from apple.

What is happening is physicsWorld doesn't exist during the time NSCoder happens, and instead  of placing the physics body attached to the sprites body into the world when it does exist, it decides to cache the one located in the SKS file,  and this is why it doesn't work.

So a very convenient way to get around this issue, is to implement a worldNode (It is good practice to do this anyway, especially if you want to create a pause screen) and just remove it then add it back in during sceneLoad:

```
class GameScene: SKScene,SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    lazy var worldNode : SKNode = { self.childNode(withName:"//worldNode")!}()

    override func sceneDidLoad() {
        worldNode.removeFromParent()
        addChild(worldNode)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll have to try this... I was under the impression that super.init needed more time to finish before setting the physics body, if you read my comment above... so I'm a little skeptical that this will work, but who knows... I did end up figuring out a fix. I store all the sprites I'm interest in, in an array... so I added a function to my game scene file to loop through the array and run the setup physics. I called the function at the end of the didmove function and all is well... what do you think of that solution?

Comment: Nothing runs on a background thread, after super.init is done, your sprite is ready

Comment: that is one ugly solution, if you have a lot of sprites, you will end up causing your game to freeze momentarily.

Comment: Maybe the sks needs more time to process something? I just don't understand why i can't set it after the super.init, but if a wait a bit it works

Comment: What are you talking about?  The init of the SKScene or the init of the Sprite

Comment: Then I have no idea what your issue is,  sprite is finished after super.init

Comment: If I try to set the physics right after the super.init call the t doesn't work... if I use an wait action with a completion block It works...

Comment: you are doing somethign wrong then, you can set a physics body immediately after init

Comment: Let me update the question to show you how I'm setting the physics body

Comment: yes that will work fine, not sure what you are doing

Comment: Hmm... well I'll look at it, it wasn't working for me...  and everything seemed to be correct...

Comment: `class Sprite : SKSpriteNode
{
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf:CGSize(width:50, height:50))
        print(self.physicsBody)
    }
}` shows the body exists

Comment: Okay, I tested as well and yes it does print... In my function setupPhysics(). I set it all up, with bit masks, and dynamic, pinned, etc... I can even print those values and they all look valid. The reason I mentioned it didn't work before is because it wasn't registering the contact when I make contact with this sprite...

Comment: So it appears that the physics body is there and all values are correct, but it doesn't register the contact, when another sprite touches it...

Comment: then something else is going on, if that body is not nil then it exists

Comment: I thought I had it, but no the contact registering is not the problem, I should still be able to collide with these sprites  but that collision is not happening... My characters just go through them...

Comment: All bit masks are setup correctly, as it works with my the method I have explained...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146812/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-discoveringmypath).

Comment: I had issues trying this out this morning, not sure that it could find the worldNode, unless I'm supposed to create that myself... I'll play with it later tonight... thanks

Comment: yes, you create an SKNode called worldNode in your sks file, and you treat this as the scene node.  This way if you need to pause your game, you just pause worldNode, and you can place a node outside of world node to handle your pause screen and pause events

Comment: I'll attempt this tonight. Would I make all the sprites in the scene a child of this node, and the nodes parent would be the scene?

Comment: Very good tip with worldNode. I had lots of strange errors with physicsBodies and joints and putting all nodes into one main worldNode and removing it from parent and adding as child again fixed them all. Apple should fix that.

Comment: Great answer, I would upvote more than once if I could. This has really been causing me trouble, and it's nice to finally understand what is going on.